# To find out the number of items entered?

Tags: java

I am a beginner in java, in the following program I have coded a program for a cd shop regrding sotring the available cds in the shop I want to know the total number of cd details entered how to find it?

```
public class Cdshop {
    int cid;
    String title;
    int price;
    String type;

    Cdshop() {
        cid = 100;
        title = "Avengers";
        price = 100;
        type = "Action";
    }

    Cdshop(int num1, String str, int num2, String str1) {
        cid = num1;
        title = str;
        price = num2;
        type = str1;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Cdshop cd = new Cdshop();

        System.out.println("cd details are:");
        System.out.println("cd name is:" + cd.cid);
        System.out.println("cd title is:" + cd.title);
        System.out.println("cd price is:" + cd.price);
        System.out.println("cd type is:" + cd.type);

        Cdshop cd1 = new Cdshop(101, "Shape of water", 75, "Drama");

        System.out.println("cd details are:");
        System.out.println("cd name is:" + cd1.cid);
        System.out.println("cd title is:" + cd1.title);
        System.out.println("cd price is:" + cd1.price);
        System.out.println("cd type is:" + cd1.type);
    }
}
```

Hope i will be answered soon Thank You!

Comment: What is  Cdshop()? is it syntactically correct?

Comment: doesn't Cdshop should maintain a list of cds? if Cdshope can only store 1 cd, the total will always be 1, can you explain your logic?

Comment: "A CD shop owner wishes to maintain a catalogue of his CDs.  For each CD he maintains id, title, price, type.  Help the owner to store some of the CD details by defining a class for the Cds.   Also provide a way to know the total number of CDs specified so far(use constructors)". I have tried answer for the above question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments, you said,

> A CD shop owner wishes to maintain a catalogue of his CDs. For each CD he maintains id, title, price, type. Help the owner to store some of the CD details by defining a class for the Cds. Also provide a way to know the total number of CDs specified so far(use constructors)

Judging from the words "use constructors", I think I know what the task intends you to do.

You should add a [static](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) field to the `CdShop` class that keeps track of how many CDs have been created:

static int cdCount = 0;

In ***both*** constructors, add this line:

```
cdCount++;
```

What this does is this: every time you call the constructor, you create a `CdShop` object, and in the constructor, we add 1 to `cdCount`, so this will count how many CDs we created.

At the end of the `main` method, you can print out the `cdCount` field:

```
System.out.println(CdShop.cdCount);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is slightly wrong.

You first need a class CD. It's recommended to make member variables private and only accessible via getters and setters.

```
public class CD {
  private int id;
  private int price;
  private String title;
  private String type;

  // constructor
  public CD (int id, int price, String title, String type){
      this.id = id;
      this.price = price;
      this.title = title;
      this.type = type;
  }

  public int getId() {
     return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
     this.id = id;
  }

  public int getPrice() {
     return price;
  }

  public void setPrice(int price) {
     this.price = price;
  }

  public String getType() {
     return type;
  }

  public void setType(int type) {
     this.type = type;
  }

  public String getTitle() {
     return title;
  }

  public void setTitle(int title) {
     this.title = title;
  }

}
```

Having this you can build up your CDShop class as follows (just a recommendation)

```
public class CDShop {
    private List<CD> cdList = new ArrayList<CD>();

    public void addCD(CD cd) {
       cdList.add(cd);
    }

    public int getCDCount {
       return cdList.size();
    }
}
```

And then use it somewhere else

```
 CDShop cdShop = new CDShop();


 void storeCDs() {
   CD cd = new CD(1, 14, "Deep Blue", "Horror");
   cdShop.addCD(cd);

   cd = new CD(2, 12, "Matrix", "Action");
   cdShop.addCD(cd);

   cd = new CD(3, 24, "The Big Bang Theory", "Comedy");
   cdShop.addCD(cd);

 }

 void showCDCount() {
   System.out.println(cdList.getCDCount());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to know the number of times the constructor is called.This might be what you're looking for.

```
public class Cdshop {
 int cid;
 String title;
 int price;
 String type;
 static int count = 0;


 Cdshop(int cid, String title, int price, String type) {
  this.cid = cid;
  this.title = title;
  this.price = price;
  this.type = type;
  count++;
 }


 public static void main(String[] args) {


  Cdshop cd1 = new Cdshop(101, "Shape of water", 75, "Drama");

  System.out.println("cd details are:");
  System.out.println("cd name is:" + cd1.cid);
  System.out.println("cd title is:" + cd1.title);
  System.out.println("cd price is:" + cd1.price);
  System.out.println("cd type is:" + cd1.type);

  Cdshop cd2 = new Cdshop(102, "ABC", 45, "Sample");

  System.out.println("cd details are:");
  System.out.println("cd name is:" + cd1.cid);
  System.out.println("cd title is:" + cd1.title);
  System.out.println("cd price is:" + cd1.price);
  System.out.println("cd type is:" + cd1.type);
  System.out.println("Total cd's are::" + count);
 }
}
```